# Image disappears as i decrease height in responsive view

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following:

HTML...

```
        <div className="header">
            <div className="container header__container">
                <h5>Hello I'm</h5>
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <h5 className="text-light">Software Engineer</h5>
                <CTA />
                <HeaderSocials />

                <div className="me">
                    <img src={ME} alt="me" />
                </div>
           
                <a href="#contact" className='scroll__down'>Scroll Down</a>
               
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS for the image...

```
.me {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color-primary), transparent);
    width: 22rem;
    height: 33rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 11rem);
    margin-top: 4rem;
    border-radius: 12rem 12rem 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem 3.0rem 1.5rem 1.9rem;
}
```

CSS in entirety...

```
.header {
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 7rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header__container {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.cta {
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.2rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header__socials {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15rem;
}

.header__socials::after {
    content: "";
    width: 1px;
    height: 2rem;
    background: var(--color-primary);
}

.me {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color-primary), transparent);
    width: 22rem;
    height: 33rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 11rem);
    margin-top: 4rem;
    border-radius: 12rem 12rem 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem 3.0rem 1.5rem 1.9rem;
}

.scroll__down {
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.3rem;
    bottom: 18rem;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 0.9rem
}

/*MEDIA QUERIES (MEDIUM DEVICES)*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header {
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
}

/*MEDIA QUERIES (SMALL DEVICES)*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header{
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .header__socials,
    .scroll__down{
        display: none;
    }
    
}
```

The width aspects are pretty responsive and work well enough. But when I adjust the height, the image slowly disappears as I make the height shorter and shorter. All of the other elements in this section/component move along with the height adjustment, but the image does not. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't set fixed height and width for anything, as it breaks the layout and where is the complete css code for the header class. this is incomplete

Comment: @NaikJavaid I added all the CSS for the header component. Yes I've read setting fixed heights and widths are bad, im new and am still getting the feel for things and need to play around more with using percentages. When I slowly reduce the height, the image and the background part of the image disappear but the CTA and HeaderSocials components adjust properly. So I feel like there should be something I could do to have the image adjust with the adjusting height.

Comment: Set the max-width to 100% for the image and the height auto.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS classes, you need to replace className by class in your HTML file.

Try this:

```css
.me {
    background: linear-gradient(var(--color-primary), transparent);
    width: 22rem;
    height: 33rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 11rem);
    margin-top: 4rem;
    border-radius: 12rem 12rem 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem 3.0rem 1.5rem 1.9rem;
}

.me img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container header__container">
            <h5>Hello I'm</h5>
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <h5 className="text-light">Software Engineer</h5>
            <CTA />
            <HeaderSocials />

            <div class="me">
                <img src="https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/7GW0WNhJ5VrLdTJDP7RXJPPbVaY=/4505x2534/smart/filters:no_upscale()/the-most-beautiful-garden-flowers-4690011-7-f6963a3136ee47dba5f85d786b31ac7d.jpg" alt="me" />
            </div>
       
            <a href="#contact" className='scroll__down'>Scroll Down</a>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm very new to front-end stuff. I thought in React especially, you can use "className" to simply distinguish your own classes so you can provide the CSS styling. So I could create a div, nav, header, etc tag and give it a class name of my choosing and use that class to style. I wasn't trying to use built-in CSS classes or anything. I tried your suggestion, but am getting the same issue. It seems like my next react component on the webpage is sort of dominating the react component that contains the image. I may be too new to this stuff to effectively describe my issue lol.

Comment: He don't need to replace the className by class, as he is using reactJs